# Can't understand 16th notes connected by beams

Tags: notation, rhythm, time-signatures, tuplet, beaming

The following section (mm. 49–52) is from "Metamorphosis II" by Philip Glass with 4/4 signature.

I don't understand how beats are adding up:

There are 4x6 16th notes in each G clef measure, equivalent to 6/4 per measure.

On F clef we have 8 8th notes, equivalent to 4/4 per measure.

So clearly I'm reading the treble staff wrong.

Are those notes pointed by red arrows 16th notes or 8th notes? They have double beams, so I thought they were 16th notes.

[image: Philip Glass, "Metamorphosis II", mm. 49–52]

Comment: I'm sure there are several dupes where triplets have been confused with ordinary note values, just can't find them.

Comment: @Tim Possibly https://music.stackexchange.com/q/61435/9862

Comment: Here's an example with sixteenth triplets https://music.stackexchange.com/q/58803/9862

Comment: That linked question is not the same. This question asks specifically about the single rather than double beam between the triplet groupings which seems ambiguous in duration to the OP. Closed, yet three answer given, including one from the person who closed it. Yet none get into the beaming.

Comment: Kind of nonsense to both answer and close a question.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Not when the duplicate only turned up after answering...

Comment: ... but I disagree with @Tim that this is a duplicate. Related, sure, but sufficiently different to remain open. The present question is not only about triplets but also the way they are beamed, which is specific to semiquaver triplets in comparison to quaver triplets. I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - maybe, but I answered a good hour before it occurred to me that I'd seen very similar previously. Still couldn't find a dupe, hence the comment. Do I then delete the answer? No! A lot of 'dupes' aren't *exactly* the same as the one to be closed, but that hasn't stopped them. There's always the option to re-open. Not too desperate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "*3*" below each group of three sixteenth notes is a triplet indicator. Rather than 4x6 16ths notes, consider that it's 8x3 16ths.

Each sixteenth-note triplet is the equivalent of one half beat, and half beats are connected with single beams. Usually, of course, the half beat in 4/4 time would be represented by eighth notes, but in this case sixteenth note triplets reside where ordinarily each eighth note would be.

One might wonder why sixteenth-note sextuplets weren't used, but short of contacting the editor, a reasonable guess is that the goal was to help visually align each triplet with its corresponding left-hand eighth note.

Comment: I'd say it's just a philosophy of using as little beaming as necessary to keep the beats coherent. Since the "and" of each beat is in the normal place, it's beamed like a normal eighth note "and" would be. If they were all beamed together as sixteenths, I believe, as you mentioned, it would conventionally be notated as sextuplets and not only would that be a lot of ink on the page, but possibly offputting to novices who are only used to seeing triplets.

Comment: The beam connecting the two triplets of 16th notes could have been omitted. I think that contributes to the OP's confusion. It looks somewhat like the 3rd note of the first triplet is an 8th note.

Answer (score 7):

Under each three notes is a little '3'. It used to be, and sometimes still is, accompanied by a bracket. It means those three notes are a little faster than normal - they take up the same time as their normal two. With that bracket shown, you'd probably have noticed, and understood. Unsurprisingly, they're called *triplets*, and doing the sums again will give you the correct answer!

Every single note-head is attached to a double beam or 'tail', so each is called a semiquaver (16th note), it's just that because they're in triplets, it's easier to read writing them in threes.

Looking at how they line up against the quavers underneath, it's easier to see how they all fit together timing wise.

Comment: "used to be, and sometimes still is, accompanied by a bracket": early practice used a curved line; later practice preferred a straight line following the slope of the notes  with vertical strokes at either end so as to be less similar to a slur.  But the bracket has, I believe, always been optional when the notes are eighth notes or shorter when the beams suffice to show the grouping clearly.

Comment: @doubleE to add on to the existing answers here: this is a type of [tuplet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuplet). The system of beams is easy for splitting notes into smaller notes in multiples of 2, but this comes in handy when you want other subdivisions. Triplets are by far the most common, but you could cram in even 5, or 7, or 11 notes into the space of an 8th note, and notate it with a little 5, 7, or 11.

Answer (score 3):

All of the notes have the same duration.  You're overlooking the *3* by each group of three sixteenth notes.  These are sixteenth-note triplets, of which there are twenty-four in a measure of 4/4 time.  The broken second beam makes it clearer that there are groups of three, while the unbroken first beam fulfills the standard practice of beaming by beat.

Neither [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuplet) nor [Dolmetsch online's music theory page](https://dolmetsch.com/musictheory15.htm) has a good succinct explanation of *triplet.*  The definition in [Dolmetsch's dictionary](https://dolmetsch.com/defst4.htm) is pretty good, but I don't think it's possible to link directly:

> a group of three notes of equal time value performed in the time of two of them, however, (i) one or two of the notes may be rests of equivalent value, and (ii) a consecutive pair may be replaced by a note of double value.

Because three triplets take the time of two "normal" notes of the corresponding value, the duration of a triplet is 2/3 the duration of the corresponding note.  For example, at quarter=50, a quarter note lasts 1200 milliseconds, a sixteenth note lasts 300 milliseconds, and a sixteenth note triplet lasts 200 milliseconds (in theory: if you are so precise in practice, the performance will be too mechanical sounding).

Comment: Interesting. Never tried timing my playing notes, in milliseconds..!

Comment: @Tim me neither, but I find that discussions of "2/3 the duration" and "3 in the time of 2" can become confusingly abstract.  This is an attempt to make it a bit more concrete.

Comment: Just being flippant - there's not enough flippancy on this site, for me! Explaining like that is a great help, but I'm sure it'll send some folk off to search for the stopwatch !

Comment: @Tim I hope their fingers are nimble!

Comment: I’d recommend trying to record precise timing. Good musicians are way more precise than you think, but triplets aren’t always played exactly even.

Comment: @ojs nether are any other note values, at least not the short ones, unless you want a mechanical sound.  Which I don't.  Playing note values with flexible time is one of my primary criteria for judging whether a musician is "good."

Comment: @phoog you really haven't looked at actual timings, don't you?

Comment: @ojs I have.  Maybe you're measuring recordings that I wouldn't consider "good," or perhaps that I would like despite finding the playing too mechanical.  Do you have any examples?

Comment: Reminds me of those people who try to perform Chopin's *Minute Waltz* in literally 1 minute.  (Most sane performances clock in at around 1:40 - speeding it up to finish in a minute sounds pretty terrible.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman apparently the nickname is supposed to be [minute](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minute#Adjective), small, not [minute](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minute#Noun), unit of time.

Comment: Of course.  But some people used the "unit of time" definition, presumably as a joke, and then took it literally...  It's also short enough that it *almost* feels like you could get it down to a minute if you were exceptionally talented, but I'm pretty sure nobody could actually make it sound *good* at that speed.

Comment: @phoog a lot of recorded music is played quite precisely. Could you perhaps refer a recording that is great because the timing is all over the place?

Comment: @ojs I asked first.  I guess that means you don't have any examples.  "Timing all over the place" is a straw man.  Here's one from me: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jApc4r65LkM

Comment: @phoog you started this nonsense, so you're the one to answer questions. Anyway, what I hear is tempo changes and fermatas. It's not really "don't play too accurately" you seem to be advocating, but it's not complete opposite either. The cembalo is a bit shaky at some points. Perhaps that's the artistic thing.

Comment: @ojs try timing the sixteenths in the allegro: https://youtu.be/HRhilRnQOIo?t=234. If you think it's nonsense why did you get involved?  I'm not advocating inaccuracy; I'm advocating inequality.  See also [Historical Recordings from the Beginning of the 20th Century](https://youtu.be/qFPW9ENtNKA).  I'm also thinking of a concert I heard recently of Ivo Pogorelich in which there was very little vertical alignment, but I haven't had time to find a recording of his that illustrates this style of playing.